# how to use/call ttf2eot (application that use to Convert TTF font format to EOT Type) in my .Net web application

Tags: c#, fonts, font-face

**1)** I am trying to implement ttf2eot (a font format Converter application that convert  True-type Fonts - TTF to EOT - Embedded Open-type) in my .Net web application.
Pls check here [ttf2eot](http://code.google.com/p/ttf2eot/wiki/Demo)  for more details.

Is is possible to use\call ttf2eot.exe in my .Net web application.

**2)** i trying to convert these files into eot format. I've found some c++ code for linux, that can do the job, but i need to do this on a windows server. But isn't there a .net implementation that can do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to execute any executable from you code, including `ttf2eot.exe`.

```
Process.Start("path to ttf2eot.exe");
```

Comment: If yes,then how can i run a command line windows binary(so that ttf2eot.exe run) which is like so in window dos command:
C:\>ttf2eot.exe c:\testfonts\arial.ttf c:\arial.eot

Comment: Mik-Mark - same way. There is an overload that takes the parameters. Check the link, there are examples. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx